# 503 service unavailable after VPS IP change

Tags: centos, hosting, centos7, vps

I have a VPS from Hostinger which was on US server with centos installed. I changed it to UK server and it started giving error 503 on few sites and few sites are working fine.

Please help me.

I tried reinstalling apache and changed IP in centos. but it didn't helped.